# Parse PHP using simplexml for field values

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

Trying to parse the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<devices>
<device name="TEMP" index="0" available="1" type="" id="xxx">
<field type="2" max="50" min="-20" niceName="Temperature (C)" value="24.75" key="TempC"/>
<field type="2" max="122" min="-4" niceName="Temperature (F)" value="76.55" key="TempF"/>
```

and pull the TempF value of 76.55.

This is the code I was trying, but I'm not doing something isn't right:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('c:\data.xml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo '<h2>Server Temperature</h2>';
$list = $xml->devices;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    echo 'Temp: ' .$list[$i]->TempF[value] . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop `$devices->device` instead without instead of using a for loop

```
echo '<h2>Server Temperature</h2>';
foreach ($xml->device as $device) {
    foreach ($device->field as $field) {
        $att = $field->attributes();
        if ((string)$att->key === "TempF") {
            echo 'Temp: ' . $field->attributes()->value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
<h2>Server Temperature</h2>Temp: 76.55<br>
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/FmOWG)

Or if you want to loop all the values of field, you can use xpath:

```
echo '<h2>Server Temperature</h2>';
foreach ($xml->xpath('/devices/device/field[@key="TempF"]/@value') as $value) {
    echo 'Temp: ' . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Output

```
<h2>Server Temperature</h2>Temp: 76.55<br>
```

See another [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/kWP9e)

Comment: Thanks! But that code still doesn't appear to be showing the data, just getting the h2 text.

Comment: @jackstrum See `Temp: 76.55` where `76.55` comes from the xml

Comment: @jackstrum See https://3v4l.org/FmOWG I have added 2 demo's to the answer.

Comment: got it, Thanks!!